# Are there any properties of cryptocurrency that can help prevent accumulation of wealth by a few individuals?

Tags: altcoin, altcoin-development

Over time there seems to be a trend towards consolidation of wealth to a small number of individuals in human society.

**Are there cryptocurrencies with any properties that could help prevent that happening?**

**Or, are there any properties a cryptocurrency could have that would achieve that aim?**

Some years ago, there was a cryptocurrency called Freicoin that had built in [demurrage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demurrage_%28currency%29), where the value of currency held by an individual would decrease over time. I understand this was intended to encourage spending rather than saving.

Possibly the concept of demurrage is a valid one even if the Freicoin cryptocurrency project was essentially unsuccessful in remaining viable. I suspect that due to the nature of demurrage, it may require people to choose to use the currency because they thought it was good for society rather than as a way to earn wealth with little work.

To be clear, I'm not asking this question to raise a discussion, I'm asking it to learn out about any discussions that have occurred or concepts that have already been considered.

Comment: Related, but still quite different: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/37910/does-there-exist-any-cryptocurrency-that-doesnt-tend-to-centralization